# Customising Checkout Workflow to Remove Payment Verification In Broadleaf Commerce 2.2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I am currently working with Broadleaf Commerce 2.2.0, I have downloaded the Demosite and its working fine.
I want to customize the Checkout Workflow of the Demosite as in my use case I am not charging any payment for the products on my site and for that i have to remove both shipping and payment verification processes from the Demosite.

As described in your tutorial http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/Workflows-and-Activities.html, the "blcPaymentWorkflow" and "blcCheckoutWorkflow" are responsible for the payment verification.
But I didn't find the "blcPaymentWorkflow" and "blcCheckoutWorkflow" beans defined in the applicationContext.xml of the site.

Any guidelines on how to do this, will be helpful to me.

Thanks & Regards

Ankit Patni

Answer (score 1):

The "blcPaymentWorkflow" and "blcCheckoutWorkflow" are defined in the BLC Framework. The Site uses the default Checkout workflow implementation defined in the BLC Framework. Refer to this:- https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/334289cfd658b6563a952f39b18e52c09caf0574/core/broadleaf-framework/src/main/resources/bl-framework-applicationContext-workflow.xml

You have to override the Checkout workflow by removing the existing Activities from it. That can be done by defining the same in your site like this :-

```
<bean id="blCheckoutWorkflow" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor">
  <property name="processContextFactory">
   <bean
    class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.checkout.service.workflow.CheckoutProcessContextFactory" />
  </property>
  <property name="activities">
   <list>
    <!-- I have removed the Payment Activity --> 
    <ref bean="blVerifyCustomerMaxOfferUsesActivity" />
    <ref bean="blRecordOfferUsageActivity" />
    <ref bean="blCommitTaxActivity" />
    <ref bean="blCompleteOrderActivity" />
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultErrorHandler" ref="blDefaultErrorHandler" />
 </bean>
```

Thanks!
Vivek